# Why git diff --word-diff shows chunks with no differences?

Tags: git

Reviewing changes is a tedious work. reviewing code changes is even more tedious. When code changes are mixed with indentation changes many people just give up.

I'm talking about thing like this:

```
-    public myMethod(String message, boolean log)
-    {
+    public myMethod(String message, boolean log) {
```

Gived a git develop environment, you can launch a simple test to try existing options to filter those irrelevant changes:

```sh
echo "hi world!" > file1
echo "hi  world!" > file2
git diff file1 file2 #show a difference with spaces
git diff -w file1 file2 #show there is no real diff (no output, cool!)
git diff -b file1 file2 #same, no real diff
echo -e "hi\nworld!" > file3
git diff file1 file3 #there is a diff
git diff -w file1 file3 # again a diff
git diff --patience file1 file3 #no luck to hide this diff
git diff --minimal file1 file3 #neither
git diff --word-diff file1 file3 #almost! a chunk showing... no diff
git diff --word-diff file3 file1 #same with final file contents from file1
```

That shows that [--word-diff](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) almost get the job done, but the chunks with changes are showed anyway, is there any chances to hide them? See -b or -w hide completely its filtered changes.

I know new lines can change semantics in code, but since I'm talking about reviewing, not merging , this must not be a problem to be concerned with.

By now I'm using [filter-word-diff](https://github.com/albfan/filter-word-diff) to pollute my diffs before take them a look.

Comment: The diff you show does **not** only include whitespace changes. The `{` has also moved to a different line. Git doesn't know your programming language's syntax, so it can't know whether that is significant or not. I recommend that your organization should settle on an agreed, common code style and force everybody to stick to it. That would eliminate the problem you describe.

Comment: I'm looking for a simple way to review changes, so it's ok for me @Alex D

Comment: Often when reviewing code you are also supposed to review the indentation and use of space in the code. But using a more advanced diff tool like kdiff3 or meld makes your eyes skip "unimportant" changes automatically thanks to the color coding, after having used it for a while i think.